# How to find a character outside of a defined list (excel 2016)?

Tags: excel, string, vba, character

I'm very new to VBA macros in Excel, and I'm trying to find/write a new one to do the following task: take a string from a specific cell and check to see if it contains any invalid characters from a list I defined.
For example:
Valid characters are: any numbers, pi, e, log, ln, +, -, etc...
Invalid characters are: anything not in the above list (ie. _ or %)
If the string was 3+x, an error would not be thrown.  If the string was x_2, an error would be thrown and stop any further calculations.
I have been unsuccessful in finding a solution for this exact issue, and any assistance would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: How about exponential notation like **1.2E-4**??

Comment: I may modify it to accept the (num)E(exponent) notation at one time, but as of now, it will accept the (base)*10^(exponent) notation.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with something like the function below.

```
'********************************************************************
'*                                                                  *
'*  Public Function InvalidInput                                    *
'*    Parameters:                                                   *
'*      InputString as String                                       *
'*      InvalidValue being searched for                             *
'*    Commentary:                                                   *
'*      If an invalid character is found in the input string then   *
'*      function returns True otherwise by default it returns False *
'*                                                                  *
Public Function InvalidInput(ByVal InputString As String, ByVal InvalidValue As String) As Boolean

    'Establish the default return value of the function
    Dim retVal As Boolean: retVal = False

    'if an invalid charater is found then set return value to True
    If InStr(InputString, InvalidValue) <> 0 Then retVal = True

    InvalidInput = retVal

End Function
```